# Ipython notebook loading nbextention

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, add-on

I just wanted to try a ipython notebook extension ([this one](https://github.com/takluyver/cite2c)), I got a bit of a problem, maybe you've come around it before, with another extension for example. I copied the directory inside `$(ipython locate)/nbextensions/` and wrote `IPython.load_extensions('cite2c/main');` into my config.js file. Nonetheless I get always the following error message when i'm trying to load a file inside the notebook.

```
WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /static/services/config.js (127.0.0.1) 0.43ms referer=http://localhost:8888/tree
WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /static/services/config.js (127.0.0.1) 0.41ms referer=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Untitled0.ipynb
```

And the it simply doesn't run.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I have found your ticket: https://github.com/takluyver/cite2c/issues/15 Why don't you answer your own question so that somebody else will quickly figure out the problem? Briefly, the author does not support the actual stable IPython release, only 3.0-dev